# How to overcome IE ReceiveTimeout issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, timeout

I have a relatively long running web service in ASP.NET. Called using standard jQuery ajax. The problem is, I'm receiving a status code of 12002. After hours of research I discovered this is an IE client issue! If you change your registry setting for ReceiveTimeout (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ReceiveTimeout) to say 60000 (60 seconds) everything works fine. Default is 10 seconds.

So, how do I solve this for a public site where I can't ask the user to adjust their registry settings?

Comment: More info. I discovered the ReceiveTimeout registry setting isn't always present! For some reason my laptop had it but a colleagues didn't. No rhyme or reason.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of asking AJAX client to wait for response to come, you can poll for the response. Refer following url, it may help
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)